# BGE my animation won't play

Tags: animation, game-engine

I started using blender some time ago and used the wiki book on blender to learn how to use it. So I want to test out putting an animation action in the game engine and I've downloaded a low poly human mesh, removed the vertex groups and made my own armature and made a simple walk animation. I did add the subdivision surface modifier but whether I place the armature modifier above the subdivision surface modifier or apply it the animation won't play. The game logic is sound I've added an action actuator in addition to a character motion actuator and I use the W key for movement to test if the animation would work. I've made the human mesh the character physics type and activated actor. Where am I going wrong? [image: Game logic][image: Moves but no animation plays]

Comment: Please rephrase the title to a specific question to find helping people easier. Form the information you provide I can't tell what the problem is. Some screenshots might be good (logic, modifiers etc.).

Comment: Just now I do not see a misconfiguration (the Character Physics type and the motion actuator are irrelevant here). You wrote you removed the vertex groups. Did you get the vertex groups back by parenting via Armature Deform with ... weights?

Comment: Not the same ones that were in the original file but I did with a few additional ones too

Comment: I guess I would need to see a blend file.

Comment: Here's the link there are 3 files but the one with the ending .blend1 is the correct one.  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3y6_KANitapWHlSRy1fRXJmeWM